# ASP.NET MVC3 Compare Validation not worked properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

Assume this model:

```
    public class ChangePasswordModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = CustomRegex.RequiredErMsg)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = CustomRegex.RequiredErMsg)]
    [RegularExpression(CustomRegex.PasswordRX, ErrorMessage = CustomRegex.PasswordErMsg)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

OK, every thing worked perfectly with this view:

```
@model ChangePasswordModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Profile";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Change Password</legend>
                <dl>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button red inframebutton" />
            </fieldset>
}
```

So I need use some generic model :

```
    public class ViewModel<T> {

    public T MainModel { get; set; }
    public ViewPart ViewPart { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I passed to view this generic view and changed view as:

```
@model ViewModel<ChangePasswordModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Change Password</legend>
                <dl>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainModel.OldPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.OldPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.OldPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainModel.NewPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.NewPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.NewPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainModel.ConfirmPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainModel.ConfirmPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainModel.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button red inframebutton" />
            </fieldset>
}
```

Then I have a problem with `compare` validation as you see in model compare validation must compare  `ConfirmPassword` with  `NewPassword` but with this new changes the `ConfirmPassword` compared with `OldPassword` that's so wired. I think this is maybe because of change in names or Ids of elements so I try

```
[Compare("MainModel.NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

And

```
[Compare("MainModel_NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

but none of them not worked, what's the problem? and how can I use compare validation with this new model? is there any way?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376322/mvc3-compareattribute-client-side-bug maybe have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have not refered the script, below I have modifed the coding

**Model :**

```
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "CustomRegex.RequiredErMsg")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Current password is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }


      [Required(ErrorMessage = "New password is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

**View :**

```
@model test.Models.password

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 

{

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Change Password</legend>
                <dl>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                    <dt>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)</dt>
                    <dd>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "invalid-side-note" })
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button red inframebutton" />
            </fieldset>
```