# ASP.NET MVC 4 validation on complex models - model does not validated on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087358/asp-net-mvc-4-unobtrusive-validation-broken-on-complex-models) but I'm still having problem with validation both server- and client-side. I want to perform a compare on two properties, set in different models.

My models are as follows:

```
public class User{
  public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserRegisterViewModel {
    public User User{ get; set; }

    //This is suggested in linked question - as Compare can only work with local property
    public string Password 
    {
        get{return this.User.Password;}
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller action is:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(UserRegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //This conditions is false
    {
    }
    return View(); 
}
```

It redirects to again register page with the validation error saying `Password must match`. Can someone please help ? I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087358/asp-net-mvc-4-unobtrusive-validation-broken-on-complex-models) it helped a bit, but not completely.

If I change the model structure like below, than I get an error saying: `Could not find a property named User.Password`:

```
public class UserRegisterViewModel {
    public User User{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("User.Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

My cshtml page code is like below.

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.User.Password, new { @class = "wd189 inputtext" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Password)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.CPassword, new { @class = "wd189 inputtext" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPassword)
</p>
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your View and the `HttpGet` of your `Register` action result?

Comment: @bump added code of View, how do I get httpget ? sorry being noob but I am new to this.

Comment: But the way you organized your UserRegisterViewModel (with <code>[Compare("User.Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]</code> is exact problem from the link you've provided (another question). That's why some additional property "Password" was introduced there additionally.

Comment: So If I do that I get different error saying password does not match on server side, updated question with error but in both cases it works on client side.

Comment: Actually, I've just tried exactly the same code (the first block), and it works greatly on server side. The model validates correctly. (As for the password).

Comment: Can you please confirm it works client side as well and if possible can u upload somewhere on github or any site and send me link here, I would be obliged.

Comment: @Ani Shroff Sorry, a bit more investigations. Have posted working for me code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (for both: client and server sides).

```
public class UserRegisterViewModel
{
    private User _user;

    public User User
    {
        get { return _user = (_user ?? new User()); }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return User.Password; }
        set { User.Password = value; }
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}
```

## EDIT:

*and obviously, the view must be as follows:*

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "wd189 inputtext" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.CPassword, new { @class = "wd189 inputtext" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPassword)
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Register View, You need to reference the password of the user model, not the password of UserRegisterViewModel model. Like below:

```
@model  UserRegisterViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Password)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Password)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPassword)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPassword)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPassword)

public class User
{
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserRegisterViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Password{get { return this.User.Password; }}

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords must match")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just updated the answer, comment out [DisplayName("Confirm Password")], try it again.

Comment: That should not be the case as it is just for display purpose, or am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried your code, if your view code is the same as mine, the only difference is I added "[DataType(DataType.Password)]" for the password in User model.

Answer (score -1):

could you please check this [article](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/using-fluent-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-part-1-the-basics/)? I think that it will help you.

Example:

```
public class RegisterModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterModel>
{
    public RegisterModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
            .NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
            .Equal(x => x.User.Password);
    }
}
```

And another [one arcticle](http://ideanotion.net/mvc-compareattribute-validation-problem-with-nested-models/) also can solve the issue.