# RemoteAttribute is not passing parameter to action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am trying to use the RemoteAttribute to validate a data element serverside using JSON.
My data field is:

```
[Display(Name = "My Number")]
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsValidMyNumber","Home",ErrorMessage="Bummer")]
    public string MyNumber { get; set; }
```

My controller is:

```
  public JsonResult IsValidMyNumber(string MyNumber)
    {
        var test = services.ValidateMyNumber(MyNumber);
        return Json(test,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view is:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CheckInformation.MyNumber) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckInformation.MyNumber)
</div>
```

The HTML generated is:

```
 <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-remote="Bummer" 
data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.MyNumber" data-val-remote-url="/Home/IsValidMyNumber" 
data-val-required="The Number field is required." id="CheckInformation_MyNumber"
 name="CheckInformation.MyNumber" type="text" value="" />
```

When I debug and step inside my controller the "MyNumber" parameter is null even though I have text in the textbox that this represents.

I know that the name has to be the same in the textbox as in the parameter and I have validated that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post how is the generated html looks like for the `MyNumber` textbox!

Comment: Just added the HTML code.

Comment: Which version of asp.net mvc are you using? You are probably experiencing the same bug explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8376646/872395 . You can either update your `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` from nuget or you apply the fix from the linked question.

Comment: From what I can see you have CheckInformation.MyNumber, is CheckInformation your model? I think @nemesv was looking for how your view looks like? I think more detailed code example might be beneficial.

Comment: I added the view code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the generated name of your input field is:

```
name="CheckInformation.MyNumber"
```

That's probably because your view model is a parent model of what you have shown in your question and you used something along the lines of:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CheckInformation.MyNumber)
```

So make sure you have specified this prefix or the default model binder will never be able to rehydrate the values:

```
public ActionResult IsValidMyNumber([Bind(Prefix = "CheckInformation")] string myNumber)
{
    var test = services.ValidateMyNumber(myNumber);
    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: That field that I am trying to remote validate is in a partial page. And that particular data element is in a sub section of the model.

Comment: I've added the Bind but still not happening.

Comment: Got it! I had to change the Prefix to "CheckInformation.myNumber"

Answer (score 0):

You can also receive the value of myNumber to pass your view model in the action parameter, Like.
It works for me.

```
public ActionResult IsValidMyNumber(YourViewModel vm)
{
    var test = services.ValidateMyNumber(vm.myNumber);
    return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```